Disabling suspend when laptop closes on Ubuntu 24.04.1
I've set up an old Dell Inc. Latitude E6410 with Ubuntu 24.04.1 with the intention of using it as a printer an Plex server. The problem is that it suspends when I shut the lid. I would like it to not do that. In my research on the issue, I've found many recommendations to use Tweaks to disable the suspension but when I install the current version of it, there is no such option available in it. No such option is available in the Power sections of Settings either. Is there a way to do this in this version of Ubuntu?

This question is similar to: How to permanently disable sleep/suspend?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Quoted directly from this answer:

Open the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file in a text editor as root, for example,
sudoedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf


If HandleLidSwitch is not set to ignore then change it:
HandleLidSwitch=ignore

Make sure it's not commented out (it is commented out if it is preceded by the symbol #) or add it if it is missing.

Restart the systemd daemon (be aware that this will log you off) with this command:
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind

or from 15.04 onwards:
sudo service systemd-logind restart




I tried the above (editing logid.conf) and it didn't work. The laptop still suspends when I close the lid. I'm currently using Remmina to remote into it to access the desktop. Any further advice?
